# WP8 write lines of text

Tags: c#, xna

I have a complete game that I am converting to windows phone. I am almost ready except for saving and loading a txt file. In c# for windows it would work like this:
Saving:

```
string[] lines = {myValue.ToString(),myValue2.ToString()}
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path+"/myFileName.txt", lines);
```

This generates a file which looks like this:

1

5

separate lines for each value

Reading:

```
string f = path + "/myFileName.txt";
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(f);
            myValue = Convert.ToInt64(lines[0]);
            myValue2 = Convert.ToInt64(lines[1]);
```

this would give myValue=1 and myValue2=5

How can I do this on Windows Phone (separate lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Isolated Storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/12/09/reading-files-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) to retrieve a stream to the file in question, then create an instance of `StreamReader` and read its lines in the usual way.

Microsoft has provided example code:  [Writing Data (Windows Phone)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604992.aspx)